# What is the default value of pandas corr()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, correlation, pearson-correlation

I am using pandas `corr()` as follows using my dataframe `df`.

```
print(df.corr())
```

However, pandas documentation does not say what would be assigned as the default `correlation method` if we keep it as empty.

Link to the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

I would like to know what is the default correlation method in pandas?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: The default value is `method='pearson'`, from the same link you posted. See `DataFrame.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)` - this means `pearson` is the default value for the argument `method`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html):

```
DataFrame.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)
```

So it uses Pearson standard correlation coefficient.